# What are the differences between Set, FrozenSet, MutableSet and AbstractSet in python typing module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, frozenset

I am trying to annotate my code with types but I am a little confused when it comes to sets. I read some points in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/):

> Note: Dict , List , Set and FrozenSet are mainly useful for annotating return values. For arguments, prefer the abstract collection types defined below, e.g. Mapping , Sequence or AbstractSet .

and

> Set, renamed to AbstractSet . This name change was required because Set in the typing module means set() with generics.

but this does not help.

My first question is: what are the commonalities and differences between Set, FrozenSet, MutableSet and AbstractSet?

My second question is: why if I try

```
from collections import FrozenSet
```

I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'FrozenSet'
```

?

I am using Python 3.4 and I have installed mypy-lang via pip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be careful with annotations and typing.  The ideas discussed in 484 are brand new, and implemented in the `typing` module.  That module is only available in Python3.5  (the latest `typing` is also available from `pip` for both Py2 and Py3).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

That note that you quoted is from a section in 484 that starts:

> To open the usage of static type checking to Python 3.5 as well as older versions, a uniform namespace is required. For this purpose, a new module in the standard library is introduced called typing .

The things that the note lists are annotation types, not actual object classes (builtin or from `collections`).  Don't confuse the two.

Note that `Dict` , `List` , `Set` and `FrozenSet` are all capitalized, where as the functions (and type names) are `dict`, `list`, `set`, `frozenset`.   In other words to make a dictionary you use `dict()` or `{}`, not `Dict`.

Annotations are new to 3.0 (not in 2.n at all).  In a regular interpreter all they do is populate the function's `__annotations__` dictionary.  There's nothing in the interpreter that uses or requires annotations.

http://mypy-lang.org/  describes itself as an experiemental typing checker.  You need to look at it's documentation to see how compatible it is with 484 etc.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc  has some abstract definitions, which I believe `typing` uses.  I've never used these.  They are mainly for people developing new classes of objects, not 'regular' users.

The `typing` tag for this question is probably not a good idea. It doesn't have many followers, and is too generic.  It does not refer to this Python module.

Search for `[python] 484` for other SO questions dealing with this style of annotations.

https://github.com/python/typing - the `typing` development repository.

In this repository, there is a `FrozenSet` definition in the `python2/typing.py` file (the python2 backport), but not in `src/typing.py`.  I'm not sure of the significance of that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have clearer ideas now (I knew about the difference between annotation types and objects, but did not know about mypy's typing vs python3.5's typing modules). However, I looked into both documentations and could not find a reference to FrozenSet, which was mentioned in PEP 484. Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like they haven't added `FrozenSet` to `typing`.  Many of the classes in `typing` map on to `collections.abc`, which has things like `MutableSet` and `AbstractSet`, but not `FrozenSet`.  So at this point `FrozenSet` is just an idea in the PEP, nothing more.

Comment: There's a github repository for the `typing` module.  Explore that to see what might be added in the future.

Comment: Looks like `typing` and `mypy` have to be used together.  Use the features that both implement, and forget about extras in the PEP.  And expect things to change, since both are under development.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I removed the tag typing - I agree it was not a good idea (python-typing would have been better, but does not exist).

Comment: Actually, FrozenSet is there also in `src/typing.py`. I will just need to use Python 3.5 apparently. Please verify and edit your answer.

Comment: I was scanning the `github` source; but yes, it is in the 3.5 file.

Answer (score 5):

Two years late to the party, but anyway...

You can think of `AbstractSet` and `MutableSet` as like an interface in Java or an abstract base class in Python.  Python's builtin `set()` and `frozenset()` are one implementation, but someone could create another implementation that doesn't use the builtins at all.

`FrozenSet` and `Set`, on the other hand, represent the types of the concrete built in classes `frozenset` and `set`.

For example, the "interface" types don't have `union` methods, while the concrete types do.  So:

```
def merge(a: Set[str], b: Iterable[str]) -> Set[str]:
    return a.union(b)
```

will type check just fine, but if you change the type of `a` to `AbstractSet`, mypy says:

`typetest.py:7: error: "AbstractSet[str]" has no attribute "union"`

Comment: Why do [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Set) say that AbstractSet is preferred for typing parameters then? "To annotate arguments it is preferred to use an abstract collection type such as AbstractSet."

Comment: @ProQ It also does not work if you need `union` or `intersection`.  I'm not sure why `AbstractSet` does not support these.

Answer (score 2):

These type names are indeed a little confusing. There was a related discussion on mypy Gitter, and Guido provided a [clarification](https://gitter.im/python/mypy?at=58e508958fcce56b20d1ddbc).

`typing.AbstractSet` and `typing.MutableSet` are the types for ABCs (abstract base classes), not concrete implementations of the set type:

- `typing.AbstractSet` is the type for `collections.abc.Set`, which is an ABC (abstract base class) for an immutable set.
- `typing.MutableSet` is the type for `collections.abc.MutableSet`, which is an ABC for a mutable set.

`typing.Set` and `typing.FrozenSet` are the types for concrete set implementations, available in the stdlib:

- `typing.Set` is the type for stdlib `set`, which is a concrete implementation of a mutable set.
- `typing.FrozenSet` is the type for stdlib `frozenset`, which is a concrete implementation of an immutable set.

Answer (score 2):

### Update in Python 3.9, 3.10, 3.11, and 3.12 (2021+)

The relationship between builtin `set`, `collections.abc.Set`, `typing.Set`, `collections.abc.MutableSet`, and  `typing.AbstractSet` had a complicated history. In Python 3.9, [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) made some changes.

According to the Python 3.12 [`typing` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) and [`collections.abc` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html):

- `collections.abc.Set` and `typing.Set` are aliased to builtin `set`.
- `collections.abc.MutableSet` is a non-deprecated subclass of `Set`
- `typing.FrozenSet` and `typing.AbstractSet` are aliased to builtin `frozenset`.

**But this appears to be wrong! Proof:**

```py
from typing import AbstractSet, Set

issubclass(set, Set)                # True
issubclass(frozenset, Set)          # False
issubclass(frozenset, set)          # False
# all good so far

issubclass(set, AbstractSet)        # True
issubclass(frozenset, AbstractSet)  # True
# ok, that makes sense

issubclass(set, frozenset)          # False
# but that doesn't
```

So `AbstractSet` does not appear to be an alias to `set`, contrary to the docs.

**TL;DR: Use `AbstractSet[T]` or `set[T] | frozenset[T]`**

##### Option 1: Use `AbtractSet[T]`

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import AbstractSet

def union[T](a: Iterable[T], b: Iterable[T]) -> AbstractSet[T]:
    if isinstance(a, frozenset) or isinstance(b, frozenset):
        return frozenset(a) | frozenset(b)
    return set(a) | set(b)

assert union({1}, {2}) == {1, 2}
assert union(frozenset({1}), {2}) == frozenset({1, 2})
```

##### Option 1: Use `set[T] | frozenset[T]`

Use this if you want to avoid `AbstractSet` in fear that Python will remove that supposedly deprecated alias.

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import AbstractSet

# using Python 3.12+ generics
def union[T](a: Iterable[T], b: Iterable[T]) -> set[T] | frozenset[T]:
    if isinstance(a, frozenset) or isinstance(b, frozenset):
        return frozenset(a) | frozenset(b)
    return set(a) | set(b)

assert union({1}, {2}) == {1, 2}
assert union(frozenset({1}), {2}) == frozenset({1, 2})
```

The longer answer is... maybe someone knows the correct way, or some Python dev has a plan.

Answer (score 1):

The set type is mutable -- the contents can be changed using methods like add() and remove(). Since it is mutable, it has no hash value and cannot be used as either a dictionary key or as an element of another set. The frozenset type is immutable and hashable -- its contents cannot be altered after is created; however, it can be used as a dictionary key or as an element of another set.

from: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset

you don't need to include it, it's built in, you just do:

`cities = frozenset(["Frankfurt", "Basel","Freiburg"])`

tested in 3.4.2

Comment: Thanks, I know these differences. The question was about how these types are mapped in the typing module. I am sorry if I was not clear.